# Spring batch - running multiple jobs in parallel

Tags: spring, parallel-processing, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch and couldn't figure out how to do this..

Basically I have a spring file poller which runs every N mins to look for files with some name (ex: A.txt & B.txt) in certain directory. At any moment in time, there could be max 2 files in this directory (A and B). Through Spring Batch Job, these two files will be processed and persisted to 2 different DB tables.

These files are somewhat similar, so the same processor/writer is used.

Right now the way I set up, every polling cycle 1 file is picked up and job is ran.

Let's say there are 2 files in the directory (A.txt and B.txt), is there a way to create 2 jobs so that both jobs can be run in parallel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that you can. Since you are new in spring batch (just like me) I would recommend that you go through [the domain language of a batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/domain.html#domainLanguageOfBatch) if you haven't done so already.

Then you may start by configuring your own *asynchronous* `JobLauncher`. For example:

```
  @Bean
  public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception
  {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();

    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();

    return jobLauncher;
  }
```

Pay special attention to `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` (the job repo can be autowired). This configuration will allow *asynchronous* execution as visualized next:

[image: Asynchronous]

Compare it with the synchronous execution flow:

[image]

Maybe it would additionally help to quote the `SimpleJobLauncher` java doc:

> Simple implementation of the JobLauncher interface. The Spring Core
>   TaskExecutor interface is used to launch a Job. This means that the
>   type of executor set is very important. If a SyncTaskExecutor is used,
>   then the job will be processed within the same thread that called the
>   launcher. Care should be taken to ensure any users of this class
>   understand fully whether or not the implementation of TaskExecutor
>   used will start tasks synchronously or asynchronously. The default
>   setting uses a synchronous task executor.

More details and configuration options - [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher).

At the end just create the jobs with **different** names and/or launch them with different parameter set. Naive example would be:

```
  @Autowired
  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  public Job createJobA() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("A.txt")
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .flow(step1())
                            .next(step2())
                            .end()
                            .build();
  }

  public Job createJobB() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("B.txt")
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .flow(step1())
                            .next(step2())
                            .end()
                            .build();
  }
```

Executing these jobs with your asynchronous job launcher will create two job instances that which will execute in parallel. This is just one option, that may or may not be suitable for your context.

Comment: Awesome example. It would also be highly beneficial if you could list the method on how to capture the completion of the job in the main thread. Just to complete the great answer! :)

Comment: @Abhi, you can use a listener by extending `JobExecutionListenerSupport` and override `afterJob()` to check the status. You can append the listener to the method chain like: `incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)`

Answer (score 19):

There are very good approaches in order to run jobs in async mode with Spring, it is just a matter of how is configured the `JobLauncher`.  The `JobLauncher` has a `taskExecutor` property and the asynchronous execution could be activated depending on the implementation that is assigned to that property.

You can find all the `TaskExecutor` types that Spring can provide and depending on your needs select the best approach to accomplish your batch asynchronous jobs.  [Task Executors Types in Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-executor)

For example `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is a task executor that will create a new `Thread` on any invocation and that could generate a performance issue if the execution runs with high frequency.  In the other hand there are also `TaskExecutors` types that provides pooling features in order to reuse resources and maximize the efficiency of the system.

Here  is an small example of how configure a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`:

A) Configure ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Bean

```
@Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(15);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(30);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

B) Configure JobLauncher Bean

```
   @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository){
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

C)  Inject your `JobLauncher` and your `Jobs` configuration

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("job1-file-A")
private Job job1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("job2-file-B")
private Job job2;
```

D)  Schedule the jobs

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *")
public void run1(){
    Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
    confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
    try {
        jobLauncher.run(job1, jobParameters);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }

}

@Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *")
public void run2(){
    Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
    confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
    try {
        jobLauncher.run(job2, jobParameters);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

E)  Finally on your SpringBoot Class `@EnableBatchProcessing` and `@EnableScheduling`

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBatchApp {
```

Comment: If i schedule my job like this , one job is executed twice, once while the Job configuration file is created and second when the scheduler is triggering it.

Comment: How can we create the multiple Job execution instances ?

Comment: To avoid the scenario @RBz is mentioning, you can disable the automatic job run on startup using the following parameter: `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`