# Spring batch - How to run multiple jobs in parallel

Tags: spring-batch

I have multiple scheduled jobs in BatchScheduler which runs at a particular time. Simple inbuilt JobLauncher which is sync. in nature is used initially.
Now, I want to run the jobs in parallel so that no job can wait for other to finish.

I have tried with the @Async annotation on my different jobs but it did not worked.

I have also tried creating different JobLauncher object for each and every job but it also did not worked.

Then, I tried with setting the jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).
But it did not worked.

I have also tried @Bean

```
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
 }
```

I have tried all the combinations given in different stackoverflow answers but it did not worked.

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
 }
```

Actual:
But it also did not worked.

As when I am checking the starttime for the batch jobs in batch tables. The job are starting when 1 job is finished.

Expected:
Jobs should run in parallel.

Comment: did you try 'ThreadPoolTaskExecutor'?

Comment: <beans:bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" p:corePoolSize="30" p:maxPoolSize="150" p:queueCapacity="10" />

Comment: `SimpleJobLauncher` with an asynchronous task executor is the way to go (The `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as mentioned by @OhadR is a good option). This will make jobs run in parallel using different threads from the pool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch - running multiple jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718888/spring-batch-running-multiple-jobs-in-parallel)

Comment: I also tried using TaskExecutor. But it is still not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this configuration works for me:

```html
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;


@Configuration
public class TaskExecutorBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

 @Bean
 public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler batchTaskScheduler() {
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
  threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
  threadPoolTaskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
  return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
 }
 

 @Override
 protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
  SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
  jobLauncher.setJobRepository(super.getJobRepository());
  jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(batchTaskScheduler());
  jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
  return jobLauncher;
 }
}
```